# Issue in test file

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to run my counter by using SV verification environment in Linux for that I have created different files and I am trying to access those file through package but my test file is not running in my top file even when I am importing my package.

file name : package.sv

```
package count_pkg;

int no_of_transactions = 1;

`include "up_down_package.sv";
`include "up_down_gen.sv";
`include "up_down_dr.sv";
`include "up_down_wrmon.sv";
`include "up_down_rdmon.sv";
`include "up_down_refmod.sv";
`include "up_down_sb.sv";
`include "up_down_env.sv";
`include "test.sv";

endpackage
```

file name : test.sv

```
import count_pkg::*;
class my_test;
 virtual count_if.DRV dr_if;
 virtual count_if.WR_MON wr_if;
 virtual count_if.RD_MON rd_if;

 count_env env_h;
 function new(
 virtual count_if.DRV dr_if,
 virtual count_if.WR_MON wr_if,
 virtual count_if.RD_MON rd_if);
  this.dr_if = dr_if;
  this.wr_if = wr_if;
  this.rd_if = rd_if;
 
  env_h = new(dr_if, wr_if, rd_if);

  virtual task build();
     env_h.build();
  endtask
  
  virtual task run();
     env_h.run();
   endtask
endclass
```

file name : top.sv

```
import count_pkg::*;
module top();
  reg clock;
  count_if DUV_IF(clock);
  my_test test_h;
  up_down_counter DUV(.clock(clock)
                      .din(DUV_IF.din)
                      .load(DUV_IF.load)
                      .up_down(DUV_IF.up_down)
                      .resetn(DUV_IF.resetn)
                      .count(DUV_IF.count));
  initial
      begin
         clock = 1'b0;
         forever 
         #10 clock = ~clock;
       end
  initial
       begin
           if($test$plusargs("TEST 1")
              begin
                  test_h = new(DUV_IF, DUV_IF, DUV_IF);
                  no_of_transactions = 200;
                  test_h.build();
                  test_h.run();
                  $finish;
                  end
              end
endmodule
```

file name : Makefile

```
# Makefile for Memory - Regression Testing - counter

RTL= ../rtl/*.v

work= work #library name

SVTB1= ../env_lib/up_down_counter_if.sv ../test/top.sv

INC = +incdir+../env1 +incdir+../env +incdir+../test

SVTB2 = ../test/package.sv

COVOP = -coveropt 3 +cover=bcft

VSIMOPT= -vopt -voptargs=+acc 

VSIMCOV= -coverage -sva 

VSIMBATCH1= -c -do  " log -r /* ;coverage save -onexit mem_cov1;run -all; exit"

VSIMBATCH2= -c -do  " log -r /* ;coverage save -onexit mem_cov2;run -all; exit"

VSIMBATCH3= -c -do  " log -r /* ;coverage save -onexit mem_cov3;run -all; exit"

VSIMBATCH4= -c -do  " log -r /* ;coverage save -onexit mem_cov4;run -all; exit"


help:

@echo ===========================================================================================================

@echo " USAGE   --  make target                             "

@echo " clean   =>  clean the earlier log and intermediate files.       "

@echo " sv_cmp    =>  Create library and compile the code.                   "    

@echo " TC1       =>  To compile and run the testcase1 in batch mode. " 

@echo " TC2        =>  To compile and run the testcase2 in batch mode. " 

@echo " TC3       =>  To compile and run the testcase3 in batch mode. "   

@echo " regress_12  =>  clean, compile and run testcases TC1 and TC2 in batch mode. " 

@echo " report_12    =>  To merge coverage reports for testcases TC1, TC2 and  convert to html format. " 

@echo " regress_123  =>  clean, compile and run testcases TC1,TC2,TC3 in batch mode. " 

@echo " report_123   =>  To merge coverage reports for testcases TC1,TC2,TC3 and convert to html format. "

@echo " cov_report  =>  To view the coverage report. "

@echo ===========================================================================================================


sv_cmp:

vlib $(work)

vmap work $(work)

vlog -work $(work) $(RTL) $(INC) $(SVTB2) $(SVTB1) $(COVOP)



TC1:sv_cmp

vsim -cvgperinstance $(VSIMOPT) $(VSIMCOV) $(VSIMBATCH1)  -wlf wave_file1.wlf -l test1.log  -sv_seed 2975249645 work.top +TEST1  

vcover report  -cvg -details -nocompactcrossbins -codeAll -assert -directive -html mem_cov1



TC2:sv_cmp

vsim -cvgperinstance $(VSIMOPT) $(VSIMCOV) $(VSIMBATCH2)  -wlf wave_file2.wlf -l test2.log  -sv_seed 1556525292 work.top +TEST2 

vcover report -cvg -details -nocompactcrossbins -codeAll -assert -directive -html mem_cov2


TC3:sv_cmp

vsim -cvgperinstance $(VSIMOPT) $(VSIMCOV) $(VSIMBATCH3)  -wlf wave_file3.wlf -l test3.log  -sv_seed 821475296 work.top +TEST3 

vcover report -cvg  -details -nocompactcrossbins -codeAll -assert -directive -html mem_cov3


report_12:

vcover merge mem_cov mem_cov1 mem_cov2

vcover report -cvg -details -nocompactcrossbins -codeAll -assert -directive -html mem_cov


regress_12: clean sv_cmp TC1 TC2 report_12 

 

report_123:

vcover merge mem_cov mem_cov1 mem_cov2 mem_cov3 

vcover report -cvg -details -nocompactcrossbins -codeAll -assert -directive -html mem_cov


regress_123: clean sv_cmp TC1 TC2 TC3 report_123


cov_report:

firefox covhtmlreport/index.html&


clean:

rm -rf transcript* *log*  vsim.wlf fcover* covhtml* mem_cov* *.wlf modelsim.ini

clear
```

I am trying to run my counter by creating the Makefile but its showing me the following errors

```
error 1 : my_test is of unknown type or did you omit '()' for an instantiation

error 2 : test_h is not a variable 

error 3 : Illeagal LHS of assignment

error 4 : new must be used to assign for a class or covergroup handle
```

Comment: In `top.sv`, declare `test_h` as an instance of the `my_test` class before using it.

Comment: I have already declared it in line number 5 still it's showing me the error that my_test is of unknown type

Answer (score -1):

You are assigning an *alleged* interface of type **count_if** to 3 incompatible types:

1. virtual count_if.DRV
2. virtual count_if.WR_MON
3. virtual count_if.RD_MON

You don't want to include "test.sv" in your package. If you did, the importing of count_pkg within it doesn't make sense.

I suggest posting your code on [EDA Playrground](https://www.edaplayground.com).

Error messages without line numbers aren't the most helpful.